# new to linq. compiler doesnt like my query. Code provided

Tags: linq

I am working on a function that returns a film object based on the name of the film passed in.

I am new to linq2entities and I don't know how to resolve the compiler error I am getting.

```
  public Film GetFilm(string FilmName)
    {
        Film temp = FilmEntity.Films.Where(f => f.FilmTitle == FilmName);
        return temp;
    }
```

- Error    1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'FilmWebApplication.Models.Film'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    C:\Users\newWorkPC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FilmWebApplication\FilmWebApplication\Content\DataHandling.cs  26  25  FilmWebApplication

In this code it feels like f is not defined, but I don't know if that is the case or not.

Comment: What if multiple films have the same title (f.e. Speed,
1936 and 1994)?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Where doesn't return `Film` but an `IQueryable<Film>`

What you should do is this

```
public Film GetFilm(string FilmName)
{
    Film temp = FilmEntity.Films.Where(f => f.FilmTitle == FilmName).Single();
    return temp;
}
```

or this

```
public Film GetFilm(string FilmName)
{
    Film temp = FilmEntity.Films.Single(f => f.FilmTitle == FilmName);
    return temp;
}
```

This all assuming you only have one with this name in the db. If there might be more you can use First or FirstOrDefault (this one will not return an exception if it doesn't find anything). Same goes for Single. You can also use SingleOrDefault if there might be ONE or NONE

Comment: Or even better: return all films with that title instead of an arbitrary one.

Comment: From his question I assume he is only expecting one film to have the needed title, otherwise it would be List<Film> temp = ... or something similar

Comment: It's obvious that he expects only one, but film-titles are not unique.

Comment: I know. I am helping him with the problem at hand as the question is `new to linq. compiler doesnt like my query. Code provided`. I am not here to peek into his database :)

Comment: ...and your answer is perfectly fine. I just wanted to add that his model seems to begin with a false assumption. Consider that this is a video-on-demand app, it could never store two [films with the same title](http://listverse.com/2008/12/20/top-10-movies-with-duplicate-titles/).

Comment: I am assing one film object to be returned in this case. When i need all films I will return a list<film>

Comment: @user3679864: i'm afraid that you've misunderstood it, you should return `IEnumerable<Film>` instead and let the caller of this method decide if he uses the first, last, single or whatever(maybe log if there are multiple) or show all films with that title.

Answer (score 0):

Where returns a IQueryable of Films however you're assigning it to a single Film.

If you're only expecting one result there are better methods than Where you can use. The common ones I use are

- First (takes the first of a collection, throws if there aren't any)
- FirstOrDefault (takes the first and returns null if there aren't any)
- Single (returns one if there is only one, otherwise it will throw)
- SingleOrDefault (if there's more than one returns null).

Assuming FilmTitle is unique you should be safe to use Single(), if it isn't then you need to consider what happens if there's more than one with the same title.

```
public Film GetFilm(string FilmName)
{
    Film temp = FilmEntity.Films.Single(f => f.FilmTitle == FilmName);
    return temp;
}
```

An alternative (if you're expecting multiple films) may be

```
public IEnumerable<Film> FindFilms(string searchString)
{
    return FilmEntity.Films.Where(f => f.FilmTitle.Contains(searchString));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. You have answered my question and taught me something I needed to know in the process.

Comment: @user3679864 no problem, remember you can vote answers which have helped and accept one as the answer